# Installation error: editing Linux compile file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation

I am trying to install a hydrodynamic simulation software on Ubuntu, but I get an error similar to the error mentioned in their documentation. The documentation has a recommended solution to this error, something that I am not aware of how to fix.

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As part of the installation, the system must compile some code to work on that machine. The line that starts with "gcc" is a compiler command. You will need to find the "x.sys.Linux.compile" file and add the -fPIC flag to the command that -presumably- is already in that file.

I would use the command

```
find . | grep x.sys.Linux.compile
```

to find it and then use vim to modify it, adding that -fPIC flag

Then, retry the installation